# python-telegram-bot - sending message

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a message using Python-Telegram-Bot without waiting for a user response but can't get it to work and I get no errors.

```
Code:
def echo(context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=-516017547, text='test') 
    #chat_id is the group id I found by going to:
    #https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY_API>/getUpdates

def main():
    updater = Updater(API)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), echo)
    dp.add_handler(echo_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `python-telegram-bot`, the handlers are there to handle incoming updates - and nothing else. However, to call a bot method, you just need an instance of `telegram.Bot`. In your `echo` function, that's available as `context.bot`. However, it's also available in `main` as `updater.bot` or `updater.dispatcher.bot`. Note that you can also use a bot instance without `Updater` at all:

```
from telegram import Bot
bot = Bot(TOKEN)
bot.send_message(...)
```

PS: if you want to use `echo` as callback for `MessageHandler`, it must accept exactly to arguments `update` and `context`.

---

Update: This reply was written for PTB <= v13.x. Since v20.0, PTB is based on the `asyncio` framework, which make the above snippet invalid. Please have a look at PTBs [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API) for an introduction on how this works now.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.